# How to map an object to another and define an strategy for not found/null properties?

Tags: java, spring, mapping

The scenario is the following: I create a resource in other microsservice doing a POST request to it. After some time, I have to update the same resource by sending a PUT request, that is, I have to send all the resource properties to the endpoint, but I don't have all them. So I first do a GET request to get the resource's properties' values, edit what I want to update then do a PUT request to update the remote resource.

So let's suppose that the entity is the following:

```java
public class Incident {
    private String asignee;
    private List<String> impacts;
    private String startDate;
    privaet String endDate;
    private String description;
    private String summary;
}
```

When I do a get request, I get the following result:

```json
{
    "assignee": "xpto",
    "startDate": "01-01-2020",
    "endDate": "02-01-2020",
    "description": "test",
    "summary": "summary test"
}
```

That is, **I don't have the value of impacts, because it is empty**. But at the moment of updating it, I have to send this property to the PUT endpoint, even if it is null, I should send at least an empty list, I can't just omit the property.

So, based on that, how can I could do a map between two objects and with ModelMapper and define, for the destination object, that I want it to have its properties filled with "" in case of a string or with an empty list in case of a list. That is, I want to define a strategy of mapping: if it is a string and I don't now the value, fill it with an empty string; if it is a list, fill it with an empty list. Never null, because at the moment of the serialization null properties are omitted. How could I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can customize `JsonSerializer` like so

```
 public class CustomImpactsSerializer extends JsonSerializer<List<String>> {
    
        @Override
        public void serialize(List<String> impacts, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
            jsonGenerator.writeStartArray();
            jsonGenerator.writeEndArray();
        }
    
    }
```

use `@JsonSerialize` annotation

```
  public class Incident {
        private String asignee;
        @JsonSerialize(nullsUsing = CustomImpactsSerializer.class)
        private List<String> impacts;
        private String startDate;
        privaet String endDate;
        private String description;
        private String summary;

    }
```